# "addEventSource" takes around 5 seconds to render events on calendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular13, fullcalendar-5

I am working with angular 12 and using Full Calendar 5.8.0

I have an array of events (length is 5000) and when I create events from them and try to render them on the calendar using the .addEventSource(events) function then it takes approx 5 seconds or sometimes more than that.
Due to this calendar displays blank for some time.

Is there any other way to do this so I can minimize the load time?

Comment: The main goal is to give users interactive page as fast as possible so you can try reducing the initial length of events to 1000 maybe or even less and then some sort of interval to load 1000 each second till all of the events are loaded

Comment: Why would you try to load 5000 events in at once? No human can possibly absorb that quantity of data on the screen at once, it will make a poor user experience. What time period does the data cover? And are you displaying that whole time period on the calendar at once? If not, then try only downloading data for the time period being displayed by the calendar (e.g. 1 month or 1 week). You can then load more events if the user changes the calendar to display a different date range. Fullcalendar actually has built-in support for that via the events-as-json or events-as-function features.

Comment: @ADyson I am displaying 1 month calendar, and there are 5000 events for that month.

Comment: Ok. What is the context, why are there so many events in a relatively short time? And why would you want to display all that to the user at once? They cannot absorb it or use that much info at one time (no human can), and the display would be unreadably cluttered anyway. And fullCalendar simply isn't designed to show such a large volume of data (because no-one anticipated that it would ever make sense to do so). Consider adding some sort of filtering to your UI so the user can choose categories of events they want to look at.

Comment: @ADyson, Even after doing filtration I come up with this number (5000). On the calendar, it just shows "Dot"  for each event, and on hover, it displays the details in the tooltip. There is no other issue with the calendar, it looks nice and quite understandable. The only issue I am facing is that it takes time to load the events on the calendar.

Comment: You must have customised it quite a lot then, because that's not how fullCalendar looks normally (with just a dot). But again, why the need to show so many events? What is the purpose of this calendar? Even with the display altered, it's still an overwhelming amount of information for users to absorb. How are you fitting all that into the page, even just as dots? It's potentially hundreds of dots on each day. No-one can process that quantity of information easily when sat looking at it. It's overwhelming.

Comment: Anyway, as I said, the bottom line is that fullCalendar will take time to render that quantity of events, especially if you've done customsiation of the default. So unless you can rewrite the fullCalendar source code, or even your browser's HTML rendering engine, to do a much more efficient task then I'm not sure there's much else you can do except have a re-think of your user experience.

Comment: (That's assuming of course you haven't done something else in your code to make it inefficient at rendering, and that the bottleneck is definitely within the addEventSource function. Since you didn't provide a [mre] of the scenario (as recommended by the [ask] guide) we can't verify that.)

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you can try, although without seeing your actual code it is really, really, hard to say what would be the best solution.

1. You can use the `batchRendering` method to delay rerender until the last operation.

```
    calendar.batchRendering(function() {
      calendar.changeView('dayGridMonth');
      calendar.addEventSource( ... )
    });
```

see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-batchRendering

2. You can use `rerenderDelay` to specify the number of milliseconds before rerendering anything to reduce the number of rerenders for performance reasons.

```
    const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar, {
        rerenderDelay: 500
        ...
```

see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rerenderDelay

3. You could set the initial view to a shorter time period, say `dayGridWeek` then use the default `lazyFetching` and load your data via ajax or whatever so that it only loads a subset of your events months events at once.

see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/lazyFetching

4. You could use the `loading` method to check the `isLoading` value to show/hide a loading indicator so that it is clear that the calendar is working

see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading